# Decidability problem solved by an alogrithm step by step difference between Decision and decidable problem

Tags: automata

How Decision procedure and Decidable problem are different from each other?
Both are having solutions in yes and no form. Is any else solution for both?

Answer (score 1):

A decision problem is a problem of the form "Is my input in this set?", with a yes/no answer. A decidable problem is a decision problem that can be solved by a Turing machine.